# Printing the corresponding item of two ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arraylist

[1] I want to print out the highest value from the second ArrayList (300) with its corresponding name from the first ArrayList (in this case, Abraham Lincoln)

Ex. "Abraham Lincoln 300"

With the code I've already written, the entirety of the first ArrayList and the highest value in the second ArrayList will print.

How could I go about this? I tried using an index method but I was unsure how to properly apply it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Names {
    public static void main(String args[]){

ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
students.add("John F. Kennedy");
students.add("Donald Trump");
students.add("Theodore Roosevelt");
students.add("Abraham Lincoln");
students.add("Millard Fillmore");

System.out.println(students);

ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
scores.add(100);
scores.add(250);
scores.add(120);
scores.add(300);
scores.add(200);

Integer max = Collections.max(scores);
System.out.println(max); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, but instead use code blocks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use this website regularly

Comment: Off-topic:  A better design would be to have a class that has both a name and a score: `class Student { String name; int score; ...` You can create a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html) to find the Student with the maximum score. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection,%20java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 1):

First find the element with the highest value. Remember the index at which you found that value.

Then print from both arraylists the element with the index you remembered before.

With the line

```
Integer max = Collections.max(scores);
```

you get the maximum value easily, but you do not know at which index it occurred. Find another way to get the max, since actually you are interested in the index, not the value.

Comment: My original post had a few errors. I fixed them.

Comment: @lugowyties Do you understand Queeg's answer?